# How can I create a large amount of ragdolls (a collection consisting of many rigidbodies and constraints) more conveniently?

Tags: objects, visibility

Using Blender 4.0.

I'm trying to experiment with Ragdoll physics in Blender and I'm curious as to how I can create a large amount of them without tediously selecting objects and marking visibility and all that.

Is there a method to where I can easily create a *unique* clone of a collection that has its own physics?

Here is the collection that I want to clone, named "Ragdoll1".

[image]

Ideally I would also like to be able to have the 'Ragdoll1Rigidbodies' and 'Ragdoll1Constraints' collections be invisible in the viewport and the render.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new collection, put inside it all collections and objects you need to clone, then right click > Duplicate collection.

The whole collections can be set Visible/Invisible.

Comment: Thanks, that did work! However, it seems that duplicating a collection of Rigidbodies and Constraints does *not* add the duplicated ones to the Rigid Body World, and I can't work out how to add them back conveniently. Any tips?